# Infinite ScrollView

Tags: java, android, scrollview, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to make a `ScrollView` where you can scroll infinitely in all 4 directions.

If you do something like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="match_parent">

    <InfiniteBigView
        android:width="match_parent"
        android:height="match_parent"/>

</ScrollView>
```

then you can scroll up to the `InfiniteBigView`'s width **or** height.
But I want to scroll left, up, right, and down!

So first, how can I make it scroll in all directions?
And second, how can I scroll infinitely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out myself now.
I used the class `Scroller`, with it you can fling or drag the View around.
And you can easily use **two dimensional** scrolling with updating the scroll in on Draw
when `scroller.computeScrollOffsets()` return true.

the fling gesture can be detected with a `GestureDetector`.

Answer (score 0):

in all 4 directions? :)

Endless Adapter from Mark Murphy : https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

But i have this class and i get the code from someone here @ stackoverflow:

```
public class ListadoSinFin extends ListActivity implements OnScrollListener {

    myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(adapter); 
        getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
    }

    public void onScroll(AbsListView view,
        int firstVisible, int visibleCount, int totalCount) {

        boolean loadMore = firstVisible + visibleCount >= totalCount;

        if(loadMore) {
            adapter.count += visibleCount; // or any other amount
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView v, int s) { 

    }    

    class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        int count = 30; 

        public int getCount() { 
        return count; 
        }
        public Object getItem(int pos) { return pos; }
        public long getItemId(int pos) { return pos; }

        public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup p) {
                TextView view = new TextView(Test.this);
                view.setText("entry " + pos);
                return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, but i want to have only one custom view that is scrolled with `scrollTo(...)` so no list